# get unix time from yesterday 0000 hrs to today 0000 hours using python

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I need to get the following values

```
Today = 6th Feb
time 1 = 5th Feb 0000 hrs
time 2 = 6th Feb 0000 hrs.
```

So I have 24 hours in epoch time. The reference is today but not now()

So far I have this.

```
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
epoch_yesterday =  time.mktime(yesterday.timetuple())
epoch_today = time.mktime(datetime.date.today().timetuple())
```

Both epoch_ values are actually returning seconds from now() like 1600 hrs (depends on when I run the script) not from  0000/2400 hrs. I understand it would be better to get yesterdays epoch time and then ad 24 hours to it to get the end date. But I need to get the first part right :) , maybe I need sleep?

p.s. Sorry code styling isn't working, SO won't let me post with code styling and was very frustrating to get SO to post this.

Comment: Midnight yesterday and midnight today differ by 24 hours only 363 days a year (approximately).  Simply adding 24 hours will be wrong around time changes for daylight savings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpler way might be to construct the date explicitly as so:

```
now = datetime.now()
previous_midnight = datetime.datetime( now.year, now.month, now.day )
```

That gets you the timestamp for the just passed midnight. As you already know `time.mktime` will get you your the epoch value. Just add or subtract 24 * 60 * 60 to get the previous or next midnight from there.

Oh! And be aware that the epochal value will be seconds from midnight 1970, Jan 1st **UTC**. If you need seconds from midnight in your timezone, remember to adjust accordingly!

*Update*: test code, executed from the shell at just before 1 pm, PST:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import time
>>> time_now = datetime.now()
>>> time_at_start_of_today_local = datetime( n.year, n.month, n.day )
>>> epochal_time_now = time.mktime( time_now.timetuple() )
>>> epochal_time_at_start_of_today_local = time.mktime( time_at_start_of_today.timetuple() )
>>> hours_since_start_of_day_today = (epochal_time_at_start_of_today_local - epochal_time_now) / 60 / 60
12.975833333333332
```

Note: time_at_start_of_today_local is the number of seconds between 1970 Jan 1st, midnight, and the start of the current day *in your timezone*. If you want the number of seconds to the start of the current day in UTC, then subtract your time zone from time_at_start_of_today_local:

```
>>> time_at_start_of_today_utc = time_at_start_of_today_local - time.timezone
```

Be aware that you get into odd territory here, specifically who's day do you care about? If it's currently Tuesday in your timezone, but still Monday in UTC, which midnight do you consider today's midnight for your purposes?

Comment: I'll try this. Looks like it will work. And yes, I do need epoch in UTC. thanks.
EDIT: yes exactly what I needed. Weird that python does not have a simpler way to do this. thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry that did not work when I use mktime. Still gives me same result.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it in a Python shell and got exactly what I expected: the delta between last midnight and now = the current time.

    >>> n = datetime.now()
    >>> m = datetime( n.year, n.month, n.day )
    >>> nt = time.mktime( n.timetuple() )
    >>> mt = time.mktime( m.timetuple() )
    >>> (nt - mt) / 60 / 60
    final result is 12.975833333333332

Comment: can u please pastebin or put your codein your answer? I can try it your way. I think the problem is that the functions are assuming my timezone instead of UTC.

Comment: Sure, pasted it up there. The UTC problem should be moot here: the timezone information is lost when you convert to epochal value; that value should always be seconds since 1970 on unix. You can test this by feeding back your epochal value to time.gmtime(). You should end up with the same time you gave it, minus your timezone offset.

Comment: you are right. This does work. I must have done something wrong. thanks a lot for the paste. At the point I do mktime I get the result nt= 1328477069.0 mt = 1328457600.0 but they are not 5th Feb 0000 and 6th feb 0000 , wonder whats wrong

Comment: Ahh! Bad contraction on my part. nt is "now time" and mt is "midnight time" as in the time at the beginning of today. If you want tomorrow, you need to increment the time by a day, i.e. 24 * 60 * 60. I'll clarify in the answer.

Comment: yes, like i said, my timezone does matter. I only care about epoch time in UTC, not local time. That is all my calculations are based on UTC time only. Will using datetime.now() be enough?

Comment: Well: epoch time is always UTC, as in it's always time since 1970 January 1st, midnight. You say you want to round down the current time to midnight today. The question is whether you mean today in your timezome, or today in UTC. Do you see what I mean? As I try to clarify in the answer, the method outlined gets you the UTC epochal value for midnight today _in your timezone_. The subtraction noted converts that to midnight UTC on _the same day_. This might not be the same result as rounding down _the current time in UTC_ to midnight, because your current day and UTC's current day might differ!

Comment: yes I got it. thats why i was getting day before yesterday as well when doing UTC. this is good enough, thanks a lot for being so patient with me.